# Fitting a 3D line to a 3D line point cloud

Tags: matlab, numerical-optimization

I want to fit a 3D line to a 3D line point cloud using numerical optimization. Currently, I'm using Steepest Descent and the error function is  a function of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$; that is, 3 angles defining the fitting line.

This raises the question of how to validate the result. I want to visualize the function so that I can check the objective function's minima & maxima. Can I do this with MATLAB and should I? Is this a common approach to analyze an objective function when there is no math formation for it?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! As a non-specialist, I'm unsure about something: did you really mean "3D line point cloud", or should it be "3D point cloud"?

Comment: yes, a 3D line pointcloud. Since for this test, I created it by adding some noise to a 3D line

Comment: I know this isn't your actual question, but drop the numerical optimization and just use [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) instead. *Edit:* Ah, multiple people have just posted answers saying exactly the same thing.

Comment: Wait, if your line is entirely determined by three angles, then it is constrained to pass through the origin, is it? In that case, do the same thing people are suggesting here but without subtracting out the mean first.

Comment: A line passing through the origin is determined by two angles (e.g. latitude and longitude of a point where it intersects the unit sphere).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, "3d line pointcloud" is apparently a set of points $P_j \in {\mathbb R}^3$ that are close to a line.  I'm not sure what you mean by "3 angles defining the fitting line". A straight line in ${\mathbb R}^3$ in general has 4 degrees of freedom, not 3.  Three angles determine a rotation, not at all the same thing.

But what I would do is find the average $\overline{P}$ of your points and an eigenvector $V$ of the  covariance matrix for its largest eigenvalue.  The line can then be 
represented as $\overline{P} + t V$.

Comment: I've just learnt from you "4 DOFs". Thank you! But in my case, I think the line is defined because in addition to 3 angles of rotation, I use a point defined point belonging to the line

Comment: Moreover, I will investigate more about the eigen methods Mr.Robert & Mr.user1551, currently, I'm investigating a numerical optimization problem. Since, I will generalize it to a model fitting, not just line

Comment: Thank you for this warm welcome! I think for this specific problem, your suggestions are good enough to solve

Comment: I wound up here while looking for the answer to the case where the point cloud is clustered around a plane - and I want an estimate of the normal to that plane.. I'll look at getting the two strongest eigenvectors and crossing them.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick...

Comment: And since the matrix has diagonal symmetry, the eigenvectors are mutually orthogonal anyway, and you can thus just use the weakest (the one with smallest eigenvalue).

Answer (score 6):

Let your data points be $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^3$. First, de-mean your data points, i.e. calculate $\bar{x}=\frac1n\sum_i x_i$ and set $x_i\leftarrow x_i-\bar{x}$. Then form the covariance matrix $M=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T$. Find an eigenvector $u$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $M$. Then the desired 3D line is $\{\bar{x}+tu: t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.