# Finding residual error of fitting a 3D Line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm trying to think of a way where I can find the residual error after a fitting a 3D line to a point cloud in an efficient way.

If I use the [eigenvalue method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268528/fitting-a-3d-line-to-a-3d-line-point-cloud), is the residual error already calculated? Or should I simply find the perpendicular distance from each point to the line and sum it up (the simple, naive answer)?

Comment: I think [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression) might be worth looking at. It looks like it computes the residuals essentially by what you call the simple, naive answer.

Comment: I feel intuitively, PCA calculates the residual already. I don't know enough on how to "extract" that out from the computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = [x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ be our $d\times n$ data matrix ($n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$) with mean 0 (for convenience).

The direction of the best fit line is given by the  eigenvector of $X^TX$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue (equivalently, since $X^TX$ is positive-semidefinite, the largest singular value).

Given a point $x_j$, the nearest point on the line spanned by $u$ is simply the projection $(u^Tx) u = uu^Tx$. Therefore, the $j$-th squared residual is
$$
r_j = \Vert x_j - uu^Tx_j \Vert_2^2
= \Vert (I-uu^T)x_j \Vert_2^2
=  x_j^T(I-uu^T)x_j
$$

We want to compute the sum of square residuals,
$$
R = \sum_{j=1}^{d} r_j^2
= \sum_{j=1}^{d} x_j^T(I-uu^T)x_j
$$

I believe that this is equal to (I'll try to post a proof later),
$$
\operatorname{tr}(X^TX - uu^TX^TX)
$$

Therefore,
$$
R = \operatorname{tr}(X^TX - uu^TX^TX) = \sigma_2 + \cdots + \sigma_n
$$
where we have used the fact that since $u$ is the first singular vector of $X^TX$ then $uu^TX^TX$ we know that the eigenvalues/singular values of $X^TX-uu^TX^TX$ are $\sigma_2, \ldots, \sigma_d,0$ (where $\sigma_i = \sigma_i(X^TX)$ is the $i$-th largest singular value of $X^TX$).

Therefore, if you compute the SVD of $X^TX$, the first singular vector gives you the direction of the best fit line, and the sum of the rest of the singular values gives the sum of squared residuals.

This can be easily generalized to the best fit $k$-dimensional space by replacing $u$ with $U = [u_1, \ldots, u_k]$ (in which case the sum of squared residuals is $\sigma_{k+1} + \cdots + \sigma_d$).

Starting at page 10 of [this document](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson/csc420/notes/introSVD.pdf) they state this as a theorem without proof.

Comment: I need to ask a related but irrelevant question. I hope it's appropriate. Is there any exercises/videos/courses I can follow to produce similar workings as you have given above? This seems to go beyond my undergrad engineering linear algebra knowledge.

Comment: I think Trefethen and Bau's "Numerical Linear Aglebra" could be a good starting point. It has a few chapters on the SVD, orthogonal projectors, etc which are particularly relevant to this question. In general I think that book is well suited for engineers who need to use linear algebra in practice.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a nice book.